# Mysql Query does not work as expected

Tags: mysql

i'm having problems with a MySql query:

I have 2 tables as this:

Ips:

```
ID  
timestamp   
user_id     
ip  
dns
```

Blacklisted users:

```
timestamp   
user_id     
mod_id moderator
```

What I want to do is to get the number of user blacklisted with ips related to an specific user. My query right now seems like that:

```
SELECT count( bl.user_id ) AS c, ips_user.ip
FROM user_ips AS ips
INNER JOIN user_ips AS ips_user ON ips.ip = ips_user.ip
INNER JOIN user_blacklist AS bl ON ips_user.user_id = bl.user_id
WHERE ips.user_id = 239925
GROUP BY bl.user_id
```

But this query results in the number ip associated with the user id blacklisted, and does not search for others users with the same ip.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match your `group by` clause with the fields selected.
Normally you'd copy **all** non-aggregated fields in the select part in the group by clause.

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT 
  count( bl.user_id ) AS c
  , ips_user.ip 
FROM user_ips AS ips 
INNER JOIN user_ips AS ips_user ON ips.ip = ips_user.ip 
INNER JOIN user_blacklist AS bl ON ips_user.user_id = bl.user_id 
WHERE ips.user_id = 239925 
GROUP BY ips.user_ip  <<-- should match field in the select clause
```

Comment: Works!, thanks, I thought I've try this group by, anyway, thank you very much for the quick and right answer

Comment: @Pablo, you're welcome, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation